# Problem installing warbler gem on linux

Tags: rubygems, jruby

```
> jruby -S gem install warbler
JRuby limited openssl loaded. gem install jruby-openssl for full support.
Successfully installed warbler-0.9.11
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for warbler-0.9.11...
Installing RDoc documentation for warbler-0.9.11...
> jruby -S warble
<snip>/jruby-1.1.4/bin/warble:1: undefined method `warble' for JRuby::Commands:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Any ideas why I don't get a warbler command in my jruby bin directory?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that I can really think of is to ensure that your instance of JRuby is using gems by default.  I ran into that problem a few times when using gems where I would forget to either set the environmental variable or pass in the switch to Ruby.  I don't know if things are different for JRuby though.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried `gem install warbler` ? It worked like charm for me-

```
C:\>gem install warbler
JRuby limited openssl loaded. gem install jruby-openssl for full support.
http://wiki.jruby.org/wiki/JRuby_Builtin_OpenSSL
Successfully installed jruby-jars-1.3.1
Successfully installed warbler-0.9.14
2 gems installed
Installing ri documentation for jruby-jars-1.3.1...
Installing ri documentation for warbler-0.9.14...
Installing RDoc documentation for jruby-jars-1.3.1...
Installing RDoc documentation for warbler-0.9.14...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have the warble in you path, the warble binary is in the bin directory  in your gems home directory.